# What does a ¨no attribute error¨ mean in python?

Tags: python, attributes

I don´t understand why I get this error (AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'ascii_uppercase') when I try running my code. Iḿ guessing it could be some indenting thatś out of place?

````
import collections
import string

def caesar(message, key):

    upper = collections.deque(string.ascii_uppercase)
    lower = collections.deque(string.ascii_lowercase)

    upper.rotate(key)
    lower.rotate(key)

    upper = ''.join(list(upper))
    lower = ''.join(list(lower))

    return message.translate(string.maketrans(string.ascii_uppercase, upper)).translate(string.maketrans(string.ascii_lowercase, lower))

string = "hi my name is sam"

for i in range(len(string.ascii_uppercase)):
    print i, " | ", caesar(string, i)```
````

Comment: No, it means that object doesn't have that attribute. Note, you shadowed the name of your module with a `str` object...

Answer (score 0):

What it actually means is that a string object has no `ascii_uppercase` attribute, Python is usually pretty clear about things like that :-)

On a less jocular note, it's saying that strings do not have a method called `ascii_uppercase` that you can use on them. If you want a string to be upper-cased, just use `myStr.upper()`.

If you need something *more* complex/nuanced than a simple upper-casing, you'll probably have to write it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

1. Custom variable `string="hi my name is sam"` conflicts with `import string`

   > maybe `str1="hi my name is sam"`
2. if you want to convert to uppercase

   > print("hi my name is sam".upper())
   >   or 
   >   [print(i) for i in "hi my name is sam".upper()]

Comment: Do *not use list comprehensions for side effects*

Comment: Actually, I don’t understand what you are trying to solve. lower >> upper ?